# Viewport is rendering banded shading, but only in the Layout tab

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

This is how my viewport looks in the "Layout" tab:

[image]

Strangely, it looks fine in every other tab. This is from the "Modeling" tab:

[image]

- This is only happening with this file; new files render as expected.
- This happens with every scene in this file (including brand new scenes).

The closest thing I could find online was something about viewport rendering being "paused," but I couldn't figure out where I could find that setting. I suspect it's something quite simple, but I'm pretty new to the program.

Thanks in advance for your time and help :)

[image]

**EDIT**: I have no idea what caused this issue, but I managed to resolve it by deleting my "Layout" tab, then creating a new "Layout" tab with the "Add Workspace" button. Everything seems to be working as expected again.

Comment: Yeah, that's weird. I downloaded the file, and it's happening on my end too, so you can rule out GPU/Driver issues and anything to do with a broken blender install. I can't figure out how to get rid of it, though. It looks like z-fighting, or massive shading artifacts, but it even happens to new created primitives so it can't be that. Very strange.. I'll keep looking, but I dunno....

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Well, at least I'm not crazy. I have a fresh file open on another window and I'm comparing every setting I can find to this wonky file, but I haven't found the culprit yet.

Thanks for your help. If it comes to it, I'll just make a new file and import all my objects from this file, but I'd really like to figure out what's causing this in case it happens again.

Comment: If you want to see something stranger - turn on face orientation. Recalculating normals does nothing to fix it. I think you created an impossible object.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Haha. I can't test that anymore because I sorta fixed it. Since it was only doing this in the Layout tab, I just deleted that tab and added a new Layout tab with the Add Workspace button, and that appears to have fixed everything. I have no idea what caused this to happen in the first place, but I suppose this a reasonable solution.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. That's one of the weirdest things I've ever seen in all my time using blender. Here's the face orientation if you're curious (although you only get the "full effect" when you're moving around it) - https://ibb.co/Twv09dc

Comment: Ah! Yes, I did see that when I was initially trying to resolve the issue, but I was already thoroughly baffled by that point haha. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by extreme values in the Clip Start/End, possibly due to some sort of floating point error.

[image: Clip Start]

At the current value, `0.00001 m` you can see the weirdness you described:

[image: 0.00001 m clip start]

But if you increase the "Clip Start" to something like `1 m`, the problem goes away:

[image: 1 m clip start]

Comment: Or just increase it [clip start] to the default `0.01 m` - that's why recreating the Layout tab fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what's happening, but turning off "cavity" from the viewport setting could fix the view. When I render it out on both EEVEE and cycles, it doesn't seem glitching.
[image: Make sure it's turned off]

(Make sure it's turned off)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to investigate! With Cavity *un*checked and Backface Culling *checked*, that *appears* to fix the issue, but something's clearly still going on because those settings are both unchecked by default.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure exactly what caused this, but I managed to resolve it by deleting my "Layout" tab, then creating a new "Layout" tab with the "Add Workspace" button. Everything seems to be working as expected again.